# Changing a view's dimensions from another view

Tags: java, android, imageview

This is driving me completely nuts, basically, I have a RelativeLayout with an ImageView and a LinearLayout inside. I want the LinearLayout to be the width of the ImageView, the height to be a constant value and positioned at the bottom of the ImageView (Overlapping the bottom).

What is actually happening (I believe, I could be wrong) : For some reason on the first pass the ImageView dimensions are that of the original image (or so I believe) which is resizing the RelativeLayout then when the ImageView is resized to fit the boundaries it's not updating the parent RelativeLayout or the children.

I have overridden every single one of the views, tried calling them in various ways and still no luck.

Here is the view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<uk.co.testing.prototype.prototype.views.RelativeLayoutExtended
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip">

  <uk.co.testing.prototype.prototype.views.FixedImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

  <uk.co.testing.prototype.prototype.views.LinearLayoutExtended 
        android:id="@+id/width_wrapper"
        android:background="@drawable/image_gradient"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

  </uk.co.testing.prototype.prototype.views.LinearLayoutExtended>

</uk.co.testing.prototype.views.RelativeLayoutExtended>
```

This is my RelativeLayoutExtended :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class RelativeLayoutExtended extends RelativeLayout
{
    public RelativeLayoutExtended(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public RelativeLayoutExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RelativeLayoutExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onSizeChanged( int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh )
    {
        //int heightDensity = ( int ) ( 50 * ( getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f ) );
        //LinearLayoutExtended linearLayout = ( LinearLayoutExtended ) getChildAt( 1 );
        //linearLayout.setLayoutParams( new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( getWidth(), getHeight() ) );

        //ImageView imageView  = ( ImageView ) getChildAt( 0 );

        //Log.e( "width", "" + imageView.getWidth() );
        //Log.e( "height", "" + imageView.getHeight() );

        super.onSizeChanged( w, h, oldw, oldh );
    }

}
```

This is my LinearLayoutExtended :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class LinearLayoutExtended extends LinearLayout
{
    public LinearLayoutExtended( Context context )
    {
        super( context );
    }

    public LinearLayoutExtended( Context context, AttributeSet attrs )
    {
        super( context, attrs );
    }

    @Override
    public void setLayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams params )
    {
        super.setLayoutParams( params );
/*

        Log.e( "set", "width " + params.width );
        Log.e( "set", "height " + params.height );
        // WHY U NO RESIZE?
        post( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                requestLayout();
                Log.e( "get", "width " + getWidth() );
                Log.e( "get", "height " + getHeight() );
            }
        } );*/
    }


    @Override 
    public void onSizeChanged( int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh )
    {
        super.onSizeChanged( w, h, oldw, oldh );
    }
}
```

This is my FixedImageView :

```
import android.R.color;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class FixedImageView extends ImageView
{

    public FixedImageView(Context context )
    {
        super(context );
    }

    public FixedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs )
    {
        super( context, attrs );
    }

    public FixedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super( context, attrs, defStyle );
    }

    @Override
    public void requestLayout()
    {
        super.requestLayout();
    }

    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout = null;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout = null;

    @Override 
    public void onSizeChanged( int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh )
    {
        //Log.e( "onSizeChanged", "width:" + w ); // 660
        //Log.e( "onSizeChanged", "height:" + h ); // 550

        //int heightDensity = ( int ) ( 50 * ( getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f ) );
        //LinearLayoutExtended linearLayout = ( LinearLayoutExtended ) getChildAt( 1 );
        //linearLayout.setLayoutParams( new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( getWidth(), getHeight() ) );

        //ImageView imageView  = ( ImageView ) getChildAt( 0 );

        //Log.e( "width", "" + imageView.getWidth() );
        //Log.e( "height", "" + imageView.getHeight() );

        super.onSizeChanged( w, h, oldw, oldh );

        //RelativeLayout relativeLayout = ( RelativeLayout )this.getParent();
        //LinearLayout linearLayout = ( LinearLayout )relativeLayout.getChildAt( 1 );
        //linearLayout.invalidate();

        relativeLayout = ( RelativeLayout )this.getParent();


        linearLayout = ( LinearLayout )relativeLayout.getChildAt( 1 );

        linearLayout.post( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( getWidth(), getHeight() );
                layoutParams.addRule( RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM );

                linearLayout.setLayoutParams( layoutParams );
                linearLayout.invalidate();
                linearLayout.requestLayout();
            }
        } );

        relativeLayout.post( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( getWidth(), getHeight() );

                relativeLayout.setLayoutParams( layoutParams );
                relativeLayout.invalidate();
                relativeLayout.requestLayout();
            }
        } );

        /*
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT );
        layoutParams.addRule( RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM );

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = ( RelativeLayout )this.getParent();

        LinearLayoutExtended linearLayoutExtended = new LinearLayoutExtended( this.getContext() );
        linearLayoutExtended.setBackgroundColor( color.black );
        //linearLayoutExtended.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.image_gradient ) );
        linearLayoutExtended.setLayoutParams( layoutParams );
        linearLayoutExtended.setOrientation( LinearLayout.VERTICAL );

        relativeLayout.addView( linearLayoutExtended );

        Log.e( "width", "" + linearLayoutExtended.getWidth() ); // 0
        Log.e( "height", "" + linearLayoutExtended.getHeight() ); // 0
        */
    }

}
```

As you can see I've tried an almighty amount of re-sizing ( experimentally trying to get the LinearLayoutExtended and RelativeLayoutExtended to be the same size as the FixedImageView ), but with no luck. :(

Any suggestions would be amazing!

Thanks

Edit :

Crude example of what's going on :

[image]

Comment: Do you actually need to use custom view other than being unable to get the layout?

Comment: I didn't need any of the custom Views, I was experimenting with them to try to grasp why I was unable to re-size one from another. I would like to still know why I wasn't able to achievable this, but for now I'm content with @GabeSechan answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the linear layout to be the width of the `ImageView` do:

```
android:layout_alignLeft=imageviewid
android:layout_alignRight=imageviewid
```

on the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: You sir are a genius! And yes, it worked perfectly. Sorry I don't have the reputation to up vote your answer, instead I liked your facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout code sets the width of the `ImageView` to `wrap_content` and provides no positioning information. Therefore it will be top left in the `RelativeLayout` and will only be as wide as it's content.

If you want a `RelativeLayout` with two `View`s in it, both of which are full width, both of them should be tied to the left and right edges of the `RelativeLayout` either as @Gabe Sechan suggests or by doing this to both of them:

```
android:android:layout_alignParentLeft  = "true"
android:android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
```

To ensure that the `LinearLayout` it exactly below the `ImageView`, you should also set:

```
android:layout_below="id/image"
```